# Invalid image: Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type. in Woocommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want create product with woocommerce api but i cant set webp image

{'code': 'woocommerce_product_image_upload_error', 'message': 'Invalid image: Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.', 'data': {'status': 400}}

how can create product with webp image ?

Comment: Are you using a remote URL for the image? If yes please share the URL

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and you can read more about it here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/28998

You can use this temporary workaround until WC have fixed the bug.

```
function add_additonal_wc_mime_types($mime_types) {
    $mime_types['webp'] = 'image/webp';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_allowed_image_mime_types', 'add_additonal_wc_mime_types', 1, 1);
```